# MySQL statement is exiting my for loop without finishing the iteration C++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am working on a project, and I need to push a list to my database. I want to iterate through the said list and execute a statement that adds said list to my table. Running the exact script within MySQL works perfectly fine. However, when I try to iterate through the list and run the script, it does it once before exiting my for loop. It won't even run any code past the `executeQuery()`. My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < addList.size(); i++) {
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO comboboxtable (combobox, user, text) VALUES (" + std::to_string(id) + ", \'" + username.toStdString() + "\', \'" + addList[i].toStdString() + "\')");
}
```

I have a driver and connection already established, and everywhere else in my code it seems to execute queries just fine. I also have this code in a try/catch set for catching SQL exceptions, but it isn't throwing anything. I am using the MySQL C++ connector to do this. The size of the loop is fine and everything should be working on the iteration side.

Comment: Side note: your code seams prone to (blind) SQL injections you should be using [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html) like this

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right. That totally flew over my head. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out after a bit of digging on the website and found that I needed to use `execute()` not `executeQuery()`.